# Intent and configured correctly manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

I'm getting error:

> No Activity found to handle Intent

I think I configured my manifest correctly. Is there any issue with following config?

```
<activity
    android:name=".Lancement"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.cd.country" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the intent to launch MainActivity, make sure you use addCategory() to specify the same category that matches your manifest declaration.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.cd.country");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Or launch MainActivity explicitly and don't bother with an IntentFilter:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```